# python histogram line styles

Tags: python, histogram, linestyle, dotted-line

I'm plotting a histogram for class and while I have all of the important things figured out, I can't seem to replicate this line style of a solid line with the points showing up on the line.  It's almost a combination of dotted and solid.

this is my code for this histogram...
n,bins,patches = ax[0,0].hist(Data1,bins=100,density=True)

```
    x = np.arange(bins[0],bins[len(bins)-1],0.25)
    y = [normalProbabilityDensity(val,mu=xmu,sigma=xsigma) for val in x]

    ax[0,0].axis([600, 1000, 0.000, 0.010])
    ax[0,0].yaxis.set_ticks([0.000, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006, 0.008, 0.010])        
    ax[0,0].set_ylabel('Relative Frequency', fontsize = 10)
    ax[0,0].plot(x,y,label="norm prob density", linestyle="dashed")
    ax[0,0].legend(loc='upper left', fontsize="8")
    ax[0,0].grid(True)
```

I need the line to look like this image...[

enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y05hK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may separately plot the line and the points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [3,2,4])
plt.scatter([1,2,3], [3,2,4])
plt.show()
```